# What are the possible scl values in objdump?

Tags: binutils

The [objdump man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) gives the following example output from `objdump -t`:

> The format of the output depends upon the format of the file being dumped, but there are two main types. One looks like this:
>
> ```
> [  4](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x00000000 .bss
> [  6](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 fred
> ```
>
> where the number inside the square brackets is the number of the entry in the symbol table, the sec number is the section number, the fl value are the symbol's flag bits, the ty number is the symbol's type, the scl number is the symbol's storage class and the nx value is the number of auxilary entries associated with the symbol. The last two fields are the symbol's value and its name.

So `scl` means `storage class`, but it never explains what `scl 3` or `scl 2` actually mean.

Where can that information be found?

Answer (score 0):

The `scl` values are defined in [binutils-gdb/include/coff/internal.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=include/coff/internal.h;h=9d742d9e68d067bbd609f133bb94f8203b8ff19a;hb=32778522c7d8777803c88684b8e428ee729f0b22#l289):

```c
/********************** STORAGE CLASSES **********************/

/* This used to be defined as -1, but now n_sclass is unsigned.  */
#define C_EFCN      0xff    /* physical end of function */
#define C_NULL      0
#define C_AUTO      1   /* automatic variable       */
#define C_EXT       2   /* external symbol      */
#define C_STAT      3   /* static           */
#define C_REG       4   /* register variable        */
#define C_EXTDEF    5   /* external definition      */
#define C_LABEL     6   /* label            */
#define C_ULABEL    7   /* undefined label      */
#define C_MOS       8   /* member of structure      */
#define C_ARG       9   /* function argument        */
#define C_STRTAG    10  /* structure tag        */
#define C_MOU       11  /* member of union      */
#define C_UNTAG     12  /* union tag            */
#define C_TPDEF     13  /* type definition      */
#define C_USTATIC   14  /* undefined static     */
#define C_ENTAG     15  /* enumeration tag      */
#define C_MOE       16  /* member of enumeration    */
#define C_REGPARM   17  /* register parameter       */
#define C_FIELD     18  /* bit field            */
#define C_AUTOARG   19  /* auto argument        */
#define C_LASTENT   20  /* dummy entry (end of block)   */
#define C_BLOCK     100 /* ".bb" or ".eb"       */
#define C_FCN       101 /* ".bf" or ".ef"       */
#define C_EOS       102 /* end of structure     */
#define C_FILE      103 /* file name            */
#define C_LINE      104 /* line # reformatted as symbol table entry */
#define C_ALIAS     105 /* duplicate tag        */
#define C_HIDDEN    106 /* ext symbol in dmert public lib */
#define C_WEAKEXT   127 /* weak symbol -- GNU extension.  */

/* New storage classes for TI COFF */
#define C_UEXT      19  /* Tentative external definition */
#define C_STATLAB   20  /* Static load time label */
#define C_EXTLAB    21  /* External load time label */
#define C_SYSTEM    23  /* System Wide variable */

/* New storage classes for WINDOWS_NT   */
#define C_SECTION       104     /* section name */
#define C_NT_WEAK   105 /* weak external */

 /* New storage classes for 80960 */

/* C_LEAFPROC is obsolete.  Use C_LEAFEXT or C_LEAFSTAT */
#define C_LEAFPROC  108 /* Leaf procedure, "call" via BAL */

#define C_SCALL     107 /* Procedure reachable via system call */
#define C_LEAFEXT       108 /* External leaf */
#define C_LEAFSTAT      113 /* Static leaf */
#define C_OPTVAR    109 /* Optimized variable       */
#define C_DEFINE    110 /* Preprocessor #define     */
#define C_PRAGMA    111 /* Advice to compiler or linker */
#define C_SEGMENT   112 /* 80960 segment name       */

 /* New storage classes for RS/6000 */
#define C_HIDEXT        107 /* Un-named external symbol */
#define C_BINCL         108 /* Marks beginning of include file */
#define C_EINCL         109 /* Marks ending of include file */
#define C_AIX_WEAKEXT   111 /* AIX definition of C_WEAKEXT.  */
#define C_DWARF         112 /* DWARF symbol  */
```

So `scl 3` means that the variable is static and `scl 2` means that it is extern.